# Rust - shared_memory crate returns MapOpenFailed(2) - What to do

Tags: rust, shared-memory

Recently, I decided to try out the "shared_memory" crate in Rust ([crate](https://crates.io/crates/shared_memory))

I first compiled the Event example ([src](https://github.com/elast0ny/shared_memory-rs/blob/master/examples/event.rs)) and it worked. I launched one instance of it, and it began listening for a Event signal. I launched another instance and it sent a signal, then both instances cleanly quit. I was able to do this twice without fail.

Then, I opened a instance and it began listening, and then I accidentally closed it. Every time I launched it again, it would return the same message:

Error: MapOpenFailed(2)

I tried changing the flink text, and it worked again. However, I tried listening and then closed it. Now the original and new flink name both returned that same error message.

I am running Windows 10 so I looked up Windows error codes and 2 means file not found. I first tried adding force_create_flink(). I also tried removing the "LinkExists" branch on the match. Both returned, "Error: LinkExists"

I am confused. So the link exists but Windows can't find it? That doesn't make much since so why is this error code happening and what can I do to fix it?

I am running Windows 10 Build 19041.450. Rustc is version 1.44.1. I am using the latest versions of shared_memory and raw_sync (0.11.1 and 0.1.2 respectively)